# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize-js

```
insert or update on table "appointments" violates foreign key constraint "appointments_user_id_fkey"
```

Estou com esse erro no NodeJS ao tentar criar uma table nova que possui chave estrangeira na migration, não consigo encontrar o erro.
Segue o código da migration:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('appointments', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      date: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      user_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
        allowNull: true,
      },
      provider_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
        allowNull: true,
      },
      canceled_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  },

  down: queryInterface => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('appointments');
  },
};
```

**AppointmentController.js**

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import User from '../models/User';
import Appointment from '../models/Appointment';

class AppointmentController {
  async store(req, res) {
    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
      provider_id: Yup.number().required(),
      date: Yup.date().required(),
    });

    if (!(await schema.isValid(req.body))) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Validation fails' });
    }

    const { provider_id, date } = req.body;

    const checkIsProvider = await User.findOne({
      where: { id: provider_id, provider: true },
    });

    if (!checkIsProvider) {
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ error: 'You can only create appointments with providers' });
    }

    const appointment = await Appointment.create({
      user_id: req.userId,
      provider_id,
      date,
    });

    return res.json(appointment);
  }
}

export default new AppointmentController();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fala meu guri! Esse erro ocorre exatamente conforme o colega acima falou: porque você está tentando inserir no banco um **id referenciado** que não existe. Isso pode ocorrer por dois motivos, ou você está passando no Insominia um provider_id que não existe, OU, você em algum momento editou manualmente os user_id no seu banco de dados, e continuo usando um **token** que foi criado com o antigo user_id. Se você editou os ids no banco de dados, crie uma nova sessão e atualize o seu Token usado no Insomina.

Um abraço e sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Tive esse problema e resolvi da seguinte forma, quando você esta passando o provider_id ou o user_id olhe na tabela de users se esses ids existem pois as tabelas são relacionadas e não a como adicionar na tabela appointments um id que não existe na tabela users.